# Align rightarrow in table

Tags: tables, symbols, arrows

I am trying to align the right arrows in my table. Can anyone tell me how to do that? Preferably keeping the structure of my table. (see example below)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{longtable, booktabs, tabularx}
    \begin{document}  



\begin{table}[h]
      \centering
      \caption{Transfer Entropy Results}
      \label{tab1:correlation}
      \begin{threeparttable}
      \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{5}{c}}
      \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{Direction} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{TE} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ETE} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{STD} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{P-value} \\

    \midrule
    Bitcoin $\rightarrow$ IPImicro & 0.015 & 0.000 & 0.023 & 0.473 \\
    \addlinespace
    IPImicro $\rightarrow$ Bitcoin & 0.091 & 0.066 & 0.025 & 0.027**  \\
    \addlinespace
    Bitcoin $\rightarrow$ IPImacro & 0.007 & 0.000 & 0.028 & 0.650  \\
    \addlinespace
    IPImacro $\rightarrow$ Bitcoin & 0.073 & 0.044 & 0.027 & 0.066**  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table presents the Transfer Entropy estimation results. H0: No information flow. Statistical significance is based on a bootstrapped Markov chain of the transfer entropy estimates with 300 bootstrap replications. Note that the sign and the numerical value of the transfer Entropy cannot be compared, i.e. determining the magnitude and dominant direction of the information flow is not possible (\cite{behrendt2019rtransferentropy}). We also test a vector autoregressive (VAR) model and test for Granger causality (Table \ref{tab1:var} and \ref{tab1:granger} in the Appendix). However, because it is limited to linear relationships, the VAR model could not reveal any relationship between IPImicro, IPImacro and Bitcoin. Standard deviation in parentheses; *** p < 0.01; ** p < 0.05; * p < 0.10.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: erh, make a column just for the arrow?, you could even make it auto math so you don't need `$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I propose to put what's before arrows in an `\eqmakebox`– and added various improvement, via `siunitx` and `caption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, threeparttable, booktabs}
\usepackage{eqparbox, siunitx}
\usepackage[skip =6pt]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
      \centering
\sisetup{table-format=1.3, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-post=**, table-align-text-post=false}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Transfer Entropy Results}
  \label{tab1:correlation}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{4}{S}}
  \toprule
    Direction & {TE} & {ETE} & {STD} & {P-value} \\

    \midrule
    \eqmakebox[D][l]{Bitcoin} $\rightarrow$ IPImicro & 0.015 & 0.000 & 0.023 & 0.473 \\
    \addlinespace
    \eqmakebox[D][l]{IPImicro} $\rightarrow$ Bitcoin & 0.091 & 0.066 & 0.025 & 0.027** \\
    \addlinespace
    \eqmakebox[D][l]{Bitcoin} $\rightarrow$ IPImacro & 0.007 & 0.000 & 0.028 & 0.650 \\
    \addlinespace
   \eqmakebox[D][l]{IPImacro} $\rightarrow$ Bitcoin & 0.073 & 0.044 & 0.027 & 0.066** \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize\smallskip
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table presents the Transfer Entropy estimation results. H0: No information flow. Statistical significance is based on a bootstrapped Markov chain of the transfer entropy estimates with 300 bootstrap replications. Note that the sign and the numerical value of the transfer Entropy cannot be compared, i.e. determining the magnitude and dominant direction of the information flow is not possible (\cite{behrendt2019rtransferentropy}). We also test a vector autoregressive (VAR) model and test for Granger causality (Table \ref{tab1:var} and \ref{tab1:granger} in the Appendix). However, because it is limited to linear relationships, the VAR model could not reveal any relationship between IPImicro, IPImacro and Bitcoin. Standard deviation in parentheses; *** $ p < 0.01 $; ** $p < 0.05 $; * $ p < 0.10 $.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: I didn't even check this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

one more example, with use of `siunitx` and `threeparttablex` packages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip =6pt]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
      \centering
\sisetup{table-format=1.3, 
         table-space-text-post=**}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Transfer Entropy Results}
\label{tab1:correlation}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l>{\ $\rightarrow$\ }l
                                 @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{4}{S}}
  \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Direction}           & {TE}  & {ETE} & {STD} & {P-value} \\
    \midrule
Bitcoin     & IPImicro    & 0.015 & 0.000 & 0.023 & 0.473     \\
    \addlinespace
IPImicro    & Bitcoin     & 0.091 & 0.066 & 0.025 & 0.027**   \\
    \addlinespace
Bitcoin     & IPImacro    & 0.007 & 0.000 & 0.028 & 0.650     \\
    \addlinespace
IPImacro    & Bitcoin     & 0.073 & 0.044 & 0.027 & 0.066**   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]\footnotesize\smallskip
\note This table presents the Transfer Entropy estimation results. H0: No information flow. Statistical significance is based on a bootstrapped Markov chain of the transfer entropy estimates with 300 bootstrap replications. Note that the sign and the numerical value of the transfer Entropy cannot be compared, i.e. determining the magnitude and dominant direction of the information flow is not possible (\cite{behrendt2019rtransferentropy}). We also test a vector autoregressive (VAR) model and test for Granger causality (Table \ref{tab1:var} and \ref{tab1:granger} in the Appendix). However, because it is limited to linear relationships, the VAR model could not reveal any relationship between IPImicro, IPImacro and Bitcoin. 
    \item[***]  $p < 0.01 $; 
    \item[**]   $p < 0.05 $; 
    \item[*]    $p < 0.10 $.
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions and comments:

- As @daleif has already suggested in a comment, set up a dedicated column for the `\rightarrow` symbols.
- Your code has way too many `\multicolumn` wrappers; cull them ruthlessly.
- The `\centering` directive right befor the `\caption` statement is not needed, as the width of the `tabular*` environment is set to `\textwidth`.
- The `tabular*` environment has 4, not 5, data columns.
- Consider left-aligning rather than centering the numbers in the data columns.
- The `\caption` statement should be inside, not outside the `threeparttable` environment. (The three formal parts of a `threepartable` environment are the caption, the tabular-like environment, and the `tablenotes` environment.
- There seems to be no compelling need for the `threeparttable` machinery since there are no `\tnote` directives in your code.
- Optional: Strike the sentence "Standard deviations in parentheses" from the legend since there's no material in parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{%longtable, 
             booktabs, %tabularx
             array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{${}}c<{{}$}} % for math symbols such as "\to"
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
      %\begin{threeparttable}
      %%\centering % is redundant
    \caption{Transfer Entropy Results}
    \label{tab1:correlation}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ lCl @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{4}{l}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{Direction} &  TE & ETE & STD & P-value \\

    \midrule
    Bitcoin  &\to& IPImicro & 0.015 & 0.000 & 0.023 & 0.473 \\
    \addlinespace
    IPImicro &\to& Bitcoin  & 0.091 & 0.066 & 0.025 & 0.027**  \\
    \addlinespace
    Bitcoin  &\to& IPImacro & 0.007 & 0.000 & 0.028 & 0.650  \\
    \addlinespace
    IPImacro &\to& Bitcoin  & 0.073 & 0.044 & 0.027 & 0.066**  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
%\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]

    \medskip
    \footnotesize
    \textit{Note:} This table presents the Transfer Entropy estimation results. H0: No information flow. Statistical significance is based on a bootstrapped Markov chain of the transfer entropy estimates with 300 bootstrap replications. Note that the sign and the numerical value of the transfer Entropy cannot be compared, i.e. determining the magnitude and dominant direction of the information flow is not possible (\cite{behrendt2019rtransferentropy}). We also estimate a vector autoregressive (VAR) model and test for Granger causality (Table \ref{tab1:var} and \ref{tab1:granger} in the Appendix). However, because it is limited to linear relationships, the VAR model could not reveal any relationship between IPImicro, IPImacro and Bitcoin. Standard deviations in parentheses; *** p < 0.01; ** p < 0.05; * p < 0.10.
%  \end{tablenotes}
%  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```